# Unresolved reference: Observable in Android Studio 3.4

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Updated to Android Studio 3.4, with Gradle 5.1.1 and Kotlin 1.3.10 as minimum versions. Cannot run project anymore due to reactivex.Observable not being found. Has anyone found a solution?

Was using rxBinding lib, also tried using latest vesions RxJava 2.2.8 and RxAndroid 2.1.1 with no success.

Comment: Tried with Invalidate cache and restart?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Downgrading the build.gradle(project) from `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'` to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'` might be help you

Answer (score 5):

The issue is that you need to use RxJava 2.2.8 and if you check the RxAndroid gradle file they are using the RxJava version 2.2.6 :

https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid/blob/2.x/rxandroid/build.gradle

If you force RxJava to use version 2.2.8 it will work.

Add to gradle:

```
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.8
```

Comment: worked for me, my project was using rxjava2 from a sub module. I needed to declare rxjava2 in the main app's build.gradle.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah the workaround* for me was to downgrade from gradle `5.1.1` to `4.10.1` and also to the latest android gradle plugin prior to `3.4.0`, which is `3.3.2`.

I did this in `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` by changing to the following:
`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip`

I then also changed the following in my root build.gradle file:

`'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'` to `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'`

Answer (score 2):

Along with the dependency of RxKotlin use this

```
api 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.0'
```

Only works for Gradle 5.0 or above

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer ended up leading me to the solution: leaving the gradle-wrapper.properties intact and don't increase the gradle version at all. We'll see if a future lib update will solve it for gradle 3.4.