# Cannot upgrading gradle Android Studio 3.4., Gradle 5 dependencies break randomly

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, rx-java, rx-kotlin2, android-gradle-3.4.0

When I was trying to upgrade my Android Studio to 3.4, the update does not go smoothly rather, some dependencies break. In my case, the RxJava/RxKotlin dependencies are breaking without giving any clue. Even that is happening randomly as I have RxJava/RxKotlin Code in each of my **4 modules** but the dependency is failing in **only one** module.

[image]

**What I tried :**

1. Invalidate Cache and restart.
2. Delete /build *module/build/ *module/.gradle/  & .gradle/
3. Clean Project
4. Try find answers on the internet and these are the closest but does not solve the problem. (They did not recommend to upgrade to 3.4)

   i) [Unresolved reference: Observable in Android Studio 3.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55742589/unresolved-reference-observable-in-android-studio-3-4)
   **Explains** the **problem** I have **but** the thread is moving to either **not upgrading** the Gradle (Which is last option for me) or making sure RxJava that is being used in the project or any of its library is 2.2.8). For that reason I tried explicitly adding RxJava 2.2.8 (I was not previously as I was getting it inside RxKotlin) and wrote a  resolutionStrategy to force Android studio to use RxJava 2.2.8 like this in that particular module i.e. **domain**, but did not solve the issue :

   ```
   configurations.all {
          resolutionStrategy.force 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.8'
   }
   ```

   ii) [RxKotlin is not resolved properly after updating Gradle to 3.4.0](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxKotlin/issues/216) which does not yet give any solution. And **I am even suspicious** **if** it's the **issue** with RxJava/**RxKotlin** or the **Gradle plugin** itself. Or even if it's the case with RxKotlin or any other libraries too.

**Edit: My dependencies in domain module looks like this :**

```
dependencies {
    implementation Deps.kotlinStdLib
    implementation Deps.rxKotlin
    implementation Deps.dagger
    implementation Deps.timber
    implementation Deps.mobiusCore
    implementation Deps.mapboxGeoJSONCore
}
```

Comment: this is barely reproducible without the `dependencies`. something in that module's `build.gradle` may be different than the others... most likely it's related to `api` vs. `implementation`. the package name is actually `io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin`.

Comment: Yeah I know the package name, I am mentioning rxJava/rxKotlin because I am not sure if it's the issue with the version of RxJava or RxKotlin if it's not of gradle plugin.  I even Copy Pasted the dependencies of the module that's working to that's not working.. still no luck.. I have updated the question to reflect my list of dependencies in that module.

Answer (score 0):

try to add `rxkotlin` to the dependencies (if not already added):

```
dependencies {

    // rxKotlin ...is likely missing
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:2.3.0"

    // rxJava:
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.0"

    // rxAndroid bindings:
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.0"
}
```

Comment: It's really not the issue,